# How to pass a React component as an attribute to an HTML input

Tags: html, reactjs

I would like to pass a React component as attribute to an html input.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return "test";
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
       <input type="text" value={<Test />} />
  )
}
```

The problem here is that input is showing `[object Object]` where I would expect `test`

You can find that working code at https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-dawn-5ro04

Any idea how to display the rendered value in the html attribute ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? sending a class to `value` in an input doesn't have meaning in HTML.

Comment: You're only returning a string sooo wouldn't it just make sense to have a local-function that returns it?

Comment: I’m using a context in my real world usage to determine the returned value. My example is indeed too simple.

Comment: Maybe try this approach: wrap `input` in your own `TextInput` component.  Resolve context in `TextInput`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to pass a React component inside the vanilla html components because there is an interface expects string only as a value of value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal function instead of a react component. Assuming you're just trying to pass a string into the value of the input?

```
function test() {
    //Insert logic here
    return updated logic;
}

function App() {
    return (
        <input type="text" value={test()} />
    );
}
```

Alternatively you could just pass an arrow function into the value:
     'test'} />
But I'm assuming you want to do some logic in the test function so that probably wouldn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I’m using a context in my real world usage, so I think a component is necessary so that won’t work.

Comment: @paulgreg Sir, you deleted your solution a minute ago, that was exacly like this one...

Comment: @paulgreg could you do the logic inside of the app function? I'll amend my post. What sort of logic are you doing that you can't use one (or many) functions to achieve the result?

Comment: Yes, I’ve managed to extact the context from my class so I’m simply using function calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a container instead create a function for value.

```
       import React from "react";
       import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
       class Test extends React.Component {
         render() {
          return "test";
         }
       }


       function AnotherComponent({ v }) {
          return <div>AnotherComponent : {v}</div>;
        }


      function App() {
          const valueField = () => {
             return "test";
           };
     return (
            <div>
              <h1>Simple Test tag</h1>
             <Test />
             <h1>Test tag sent as props to another react component</h1>
             <AnotherComponent v={<Test />} />
             <h1>Test tag sent as attribute to a input type=text</h1>
             <h2>Expected output :</h2>
             <input type="text" value="test" />
             <h2>My problem :</h2>
             <input type="text" value={valueField()} />
             <h2>Solution ?</h2>
            </div>
          );
        }


    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```